# extern array as non-type template argument with clang c++1z

Tags: c++, clang, c++17

```
template<int const * pci> struct X {};
extern int const ai[];
X<ai> xi;
int const ai[] = {0,1,2,3};
```

If I try to compile this code with "clang++ -std=c++1z" it result in error:

> test.cpp:4:3: error: non-type template argument refers to subobject '&ai'

But it isn't subobject.

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_parameters doesn't list any suitable limitation for extern arrays in '(since C++17)' section for non-type arguments.

Such code works fine with -std=c++14. And GCC also compiles it without errors in c++1z mode: https://godbolt.org/g/K9wZ4g

Is it a clang bug? Or is this code wrong?

Comment: "*But it isn't subobject.*" Yes, it is a subobject. An array in C++ can decay into a pointer to the first subobject element in the array. Now, that's not the say that the compiler should fail for that. But it is getting a pointer to a subobject.

Comment: @NicolBolas The fun part about this is that [temp.arg.nontype]/1 bans pointers to subobjects, and then [the next paragraph](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.arg.nontype#2) has an example that matches the OP's.

Comment: Now I'm totally confused. I've reread what standard means by subobject and yes, array element is a subobject. Looks like there is nothing in the standard which allows using arrays as pointer non-type template arguments. Not only extern but any arrays.

Comment: [CWG 2043](http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/cwg_active.html#2043) seems to be related.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it's a clang bug, confirmed by clang developer and has been fixed in trunk ([r311970](http://llvm.org/viewvc/llvm-project?view=revision&revision=311970)).
http://lists.llvm.org/pipermail/cfe-dev/2017-August/055249.html

Meanwhile, to work around it, you need to write the length of array in the declaration explicitly.

```
extern int const ai[4];
```